# How to run scheduled job startup so that it is interactive

Tags: powershell

I cannot figure out a way to get a **scheduled job** to **run at startup**, it runs but just in background, not interactive, although I have set the job option to interactive:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name runatstartup `
    -ScriptBlock { start chrome } `
    -Trigger (New-JobTrigger -AtStartup)

Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName runatstartup `
    -TaskPath Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs `
    -Principal (New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -Logontype Interactive -Userid $env:USERNAME)
```

The same command works fine, programs show up normally if I replace `-atstartup` by `-atlogon` or `-once`, `-daily`.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Code and title fixing

Comment: For starting chrome (or similar) you might want to use the more traditional and arguably simpler method of putting a shortcut in your startup folder. See [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-program-automatically-windows-starts#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: That's good, but I want to write a script that utilizes the job schedulers cmdlets, including other options for scheduling computer, like open a file daily at a specific time, run programs at logon ... so it's hard to add start up feature to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AtStartup` is before the login screen shows up so there is no "Desktop" to interact with. Once you log in (manually or automatically as part of the startup process) a new desktop session will start, but your program has already started and will not be associated with that newly started desktop.

Switch to `AtLogin`, or if you are using some other program than chrome that you have control over the code split the code into two and make one a Service that starts at startup and the other the UI component that starts at login.

Comment: Thank you!! So what is the parameter -atstartup used for? and how does task scheduler work when running at startup?

Comment: AtStartup is used for scripts/programs you want to run when the system boots but before the first user logs in. The task scheduler works at startup the same way it works everywhere else, it is just that programs started by the task scheduler will not be associated with any desktop session because there are no desktops yet to associate with.